# Getting Error While Adding Font to an Angular 5 Project

Tags: css, angular, typescript, fonts

I am new to Angular 5.I tried to add an new font for my project.I created a 'assets' folder in root directory and created 'fonts' and 'images' folder under assets folder.I referred an image from images folder in my project by the same way i tried to refer an font.Images are getting referred but fonts are not working for me.I am getting an error like 'NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "./assets/fonts/taun_elango_abirami.woff"' .

**My css file:**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Abirami';
src: url('../../../../assets/fonts/taun_elango_abirami.woff') format('woff');
}

.content-title {
font-family: Abirami;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: screenshot exception is different from what you have mentioned in the question. it's failing to parse the file. try to import the fresh copy of that file and check

Comment: You are using angular cli ?

Comment: i am getting this exception only when i refer this woff file in css so that i mentioned that in the question. - @Prithivi Raj

Comment: yes i am using angular cli..but it is not installed properly.

Comment: Tried without specifying format property?

Comment: tried it still getting the same @ Ankit Kapoor